# Conduction and ionic conduction

Tags: electricity, conductors, ions

How is ionic conduction different from normal conduction? Do the electrons that leave atoms completely conduct in ionic conduction while in normal conduction the conduction takes place through valence electrons of the conductor?

Comment: You have to clarify where this ionic conduction is considered. In an ionized gas, in an electrolyte or in a solid.

Answer (score 1):

In normal conduction, the nuclei stay stationary while the electrons have a momentum distribution that is centered around a finite non-zero momentum vector. In some sense, electrons do leave their nuclei as the electrons pass through them.

In ionic conduction, the charged nuclei move while the electrons tag along. In other words, the electrons never leave their nuclei. When you have a material with very large band gap, only ionic conduction can happen... Because the electrons are not dynamical with respect to specific nuclei positionings. However the nuclei positionings (and the bands themselves) can change which makes the system dynamical.

According to Born Oppenheimer Approximation, one can consider nuclei motion classically "in most cases", by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic conduction, there are chemical reactions taking place at the anode (oxidation) and cathode (reduction).
What this means is that, at the anode (in simple words) the negative ions lose an electron and form a molecule (uncharged) or the metal as anode goes into the solution as a positive ion and the opposite happens at the cathode.
In short, ionic conduction has both positive and negative charges involved, while in conduction only electrons are involved - there is no flow of positive charges.

Comment: You can have ionic conduction, say in many oxides, because the charged oxygen vacancies are mobile. This is the basis for oxygen sensors in automobile engines. Further, in semiconductors and many metals there are positive charges flowing as well as electrons (the Hall coefficient in aluminum can be negative _or_ positive, depending on experimental conditions).

Comment: @Jon Custer I think that it's due to the displacement of the electrons that it appears that holes are moving. In either case (metals or semiconductors) it is the electrons that move. It is supported by the band theory and the electron mobility. Although I agree that separate data exists for hole mobility primarily because a doped semiconductor isn't the same as an intrinsic semiconductor.

Comment: Is it true that all ionic conduction involves oxidation and reduction? I was trying to get an answer to that question just now; at low voltages salt water for instance will conduct electricity, but neither hydrogen or chloride gas seems to be formed below a sufficient threshold voltage. But where does the current come from then? You cant just have the chloride ions pile up on the electrode? That type of dielectric displacement should saturate very quickly, cancelling the voltage. So what gives? Where do the atoms go?

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn No. You can have a circular pipe filled with salt water, and apply an electric field to a small part of it, and it will have a current of literal ions, with no chemical reaction involved. However, if you put a ionic conductor as part of an *electronic* circuit, then yes, there has to be a redox reaction, and the current is purely electronic. There will be no moving ions.